# Ignore certain commands in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, console

For normal use, I want my script to output a lot of Write-Host to highlight information with colour (I am aware of how -Host commands can create some confusion beside pipeline commands as -Host commands just push to the console, but I am ok with that). In my script, there are a few hundred Write-Host statements and I have simple logic to make the script attended or unattended using some choice options along the way, but I realised that at a certain point I might want to make it completely silent, ideally without having to delete all of the Write-Host statements.

So, might there be a way to put in some kind of directive to a script to make it globally ignore all Write-Host commands (or for selected regions) and then my script can run completely silently when I want it to?

Comment: Consider `Write-Verbose` and enabling your script to use the `-Verbose` switch.

Comment: This would mean losing all colour to highlight information in the text output right? I think you are right that Write-Verbose probably does sound like a good solution, but it's a shame that Microsoft do not simply add `-ForegroundColor` and `-BackgroundColor` as options to these other Cmdlets. I don't know why they would not provide that functionality. (Indeed, as of PS v5, Write-Host is just a wrapper for Write-Information, so why not have the colour options!).

Comment: I believe you're correct about the lack of color - but relying on color is not the best of practices, as a color-blind user may lose information that way.

Comment: @YorSubs - the verbose text is usually written in cyan. the warning text is usually written in orange. the information text is usually written in white. that otta give you enuf variety. [*grin*]

Comment: You could wrap write-host in your own function - e.g. write-conditional with the same parameters and then set a global variable (shudder) to control whether that actually does anything or not. Basically your own minimal logging framework.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'll do @mclayton (<doh> don't know why I didn't think of that!). Global variables are good enough (not every script is for Production! Most are just helpers etc). Yes, I'll do that, the only person using the script will be me and a few others so this will be handy to collect what we need and write a few outputs when running silently. Thanks!